# Selected column alias name in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

How to put alias column name(CO_NUMBER) in where clause.
I tried with alias name but its not working, do i need to put whole condition mention in column CO_NUMBER ?

```
Select  A_TBL.ID, A_TBL.EmpId,
        B_TBL.Tans, 
        DBMS_LOB.SubStr( TXT, 
            DBMS_LOB.InStr(TXT, '"', DBMS_LOB.InStr(TXT, '"CompanyNumber":"') + Length('"CompanyNumber":"'), 1  ) - (DBMS_LOB.InStr(TXT, '"CompanyNumber":"') + Length('"CompanyNumber":"')),
            DBMS_LOB.InStr(TXT, '"CompanyNumber":"') + Length('"CompanyNumber":"')
          ) "COMPANY NUMBER"
From
    A_TBL join B_Tbl on A_TBL.id = B_TBL.id  
Where "COMPANY NUMBER" = 'A1'
```

Answer (score 1):

To use a *named expression* in a `WHERE` clause you need to officially generate it in a subquery. For example:

```
select *
from ( -- subquery starts here
  select
    ID,
    EmpId,
    DBMS_LOB.SubStr( TXT, 
      DBMS_LOB.InStr(TXT, '"', 
      DBMS_LOB.InStr(TXT, '"CompanyNumber":"') + Length('"CompanyNumber":"'), 
      1  ) - (DBMS_LOB.InStr(TXT, '"CompanyNumber":"') 
      + Length('"CompanyNumber":"')),
      DBMS_LOB.InStr(TXT, '"CompanyNumber":"') +
      Length('"CompanyNumber":"')
    ) as CO_NUMBER
  from A_TBL
) x -- subquery ends here
where CO_NUMBER = 'A1'
```

Edit -- Adding an alias with extra characters.

You can enclose the alias with double quotes to use it anywhere an alias is valid. For example:

```
select *
from (
  select a, b, a + b as "A and B" from t
) x
where "A and B" > 6
```

Comment: I'd rather use common-table-expression, that with tb2 as (select ID, EmpId, DBMS_LOB.SubS... )

Comment: if alias is "Company Number" then how can i mention in where clause?

Comment: @TheImpaler I am getting below error
 [Error] Execution (35: 30): ORA-00904: "COMPANY NUMBER": invalid identifier

Comment: Works well for me in Oracle. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ty8An8Sl).